# Remove JSON element if key equals true (jq)

Tags: json, jq

Given JSON:

```
[
  {
    "1": "false"
    "2": "true",
    "3": "true"
  },
  {
    "1": "false"
    "2": "false",
    "3": "false"
  },
  {
    "1": "true"
    "2": "true",
    "3": "true"
  }
]
```

Given array as an argument passed to jq:

```
["1","2","3"]
```

Need to remove JSON element using jq tool if at least one key is not "true".

Desired output:

```
[
  {
    "1": "false"
    "2": "true",
    "3": "true"
  },
  {
    "1": "true"
    "2": "true",
    "3": "true"
  }
]
```

Given JSON:

```
[
  {
    "1": "false"
    "2": "true",
    "3": "true"
  },
  {
    "1": "false"
    "2": "false",
    "3": "false"
  },
  {
    "1": "true"
    "2": "true",
    "3": "true"
  }
]
```

Given array as an argument passed to jq:

```
["1","2","3"]
```

Need to remove JSON element using jq tool if at least one key is not "true".

Desired output:

```
[
  {
    "1": "false"
    "2": "true",
    "3": "true"
  },
  {
    "1": "true"
    "2": "true",
    "3": "true"
  }
]
```

Comment: Why is the question's content duplicated?

Comment: Is it always `[1,2,3]`? Can you show an example where your objects' keys don't match the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what role the argument `["1","2","3"]` should play, but apart from that, you can convert the object items from string to boolean using `fromjson`, then aggregate them appropriately, and use this result in a `map(select(…))` clause to filter the input array.

Now, if you want to remove items

> if at least one key is not "true"

meaning you want to keep only those that are entirely `true`, use the `all` aggregator:

```bash
jq 'map(select(map(fromjson) | all))'
```

```json
[
  {
    "1": "true",
    "2": "true",
    "3": "true"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WEVgZ9Y5W3_B)

But if, as your desired output suggests, you want to remove those items that are entirely `false`, meaning to keep only those where there is at least one value which is `true`, use the `any` aggregator:

```bash
jq 'map(select(map(fromjson) | any))'
```

```json
[
  {
    "1": "false",
    "2": "true",
    "3": "true"
  },
  {
    "1": "true",
    "2": "true",
    "3": "true"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/iQoTuq-WkDm)

Comment: My guess: the array argument is the list of keys to care about when deciding if an object has a true value or not.

Comment: @chepner Would be my guess, too, but for being sample data, I also would've expected it to not cover the entire set of input data keys, so it's role could be intuitively reflected in the desired output.